# XPATH - retrieve class title and the one above

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="option-facility">
            <span class="icon icon-18 icon-ki-close ng-isolate-scope" tooltip="" title="" data-original-title="Private bath"></span>
    </div>
```

I want XPATH to return the original title "Private Bath" and also the word "close" from above OR to be more simple, I could specify the word "Private bath" then get the status of it: "icon-ki-close" would be fine. Trying variations of this with no luck:

```
//title[text()='data-original-title']/following-sibling::span/@icon-ki-close
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//span[@data-original-title-'Private bath']/@class, 'icon-ki-'), ' ')
```